# Title left Align the Title and write the authors name beneath it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

How to  left aligned the title, authors and their description:

[image: Align]

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful. I see Elsevier in the corner, so why not ask them if you're submitting a paper with them? If not, are you just interested in duplicating this output in (say) `article`?

Comment: I just want to know how to aligned the title on left hand side

Comment: The class `elsarticle` (if that is what you are using) has different formats for the title depending on what your class options are. Changing only the alignment of the title for all possibilities would be a bit complex, so it would help to see your `\documentclass` command at least.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you can always format something visually.

[image]

```
\documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.78\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\Large 
Unified solution for the Legendre equation in the interval $[-1,1]$---An 
example of solving singular-ordinary differential equations\\[2ex]
\large 
Quing-Hua Zhang\textsuperscript{a}, Jian Ma\textsuperscript{b,\textasteriskcentered}, 
Yuanyuan Qu\textsuperscript{a}\\[1ex]
\footnotesize
\textsuperscript{a}\emph{The First Institute of Oceanography, \dots}\\
\textsuperscript{b}\emph{College of Marine Sciences, \dots}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Dan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37136/dan) said in the comments, you just need to set the correct option in `\documentclass`, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass[preprint, 5p, lefttitle]{elsarticle}
```

The full list of options is available at [elsevier guide](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf).